# Find the Nearest Point of $ y $ from a Probability Simplex.

Tags: convex-optimization

I need to compute the nearest point of $x$ from a probability simplex.
Formally, I want to ask if there is a close form for the solution to the following optimization problem: for $y\in \mathbb{R}^k$,

$$\min\limits_{x} \|x-y\|^2_2 $$

$$s.t. \ \sum\limits_{i=1}^k x_i =1,\  x_i \geq 0 ,\ \forall i \in[k]$$

If not, how can I derive an iterative algorithm to find the unique solution?
Thanks!

Comment: since this convex program has only affine constraints, the KKT conditions should be enough to solve the problem for you. Do you know what these are?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.6081

Comment: Despite the title, the answer there covers all vectors.

Comment: Simple derivation and code - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2402345/33.